dash mechanic for a game in godot 4
Godot Version
4.2.2
Question
hello i am very very new to Godot so thank you for helping me. i am working on a 2d platformer and i am trying to add a dash to the game where the player moves towards the mouse and i got it working however when i dash diagonally it seems to go about half the distance as if i go straight up, down, left, or right, here is the script:

extends CharacterBody2D
@onready var sprite_0001_png = $"Sprite-0001_png"

const dash_time = 0.1
const dash_speed = 600
var dashing = false
var dash_charge = 1

var movement_lock = false
const SPEED = 250
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -600
var death = 0
var player_pos
var mouse_pos

func _process(delta):
    mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    player_pos = get_global_position()
    pass


    

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
func player_die():
    velocity = Vector2(0, 0)
    movement_lock = true
    await get_tree().create_timer(1).timeout
    dashing = true
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
    movement_lock = false

            
func _physics_process(delta):
    dash()
    

    if not movement_lock == true and not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if is_on_floor() and dash_charge < 1:
        dash_charge += 1

    # Handle jump.
    if not movement_lock == true and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    if not movement_lock == true:
        var direction = Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right")
        if direction:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
        else:
            velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, 15)
                
    var isright = velocity.x < 0
    sprite_0001_png.flip_h= isright
            
            
    move_and_slide()
func dash():
    print(mouse_pos)
    if dash_charge > 0 and not dashing:
        var dir
        
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("dash"):
            
            velocity = Vector2(0, 0)
            
            movement_lock = true
            dash_charge -= 1
            dashing = true
            
            dir = (mouse_pos - player_pos)
            
        
            dir = dir.normalized()
            
        
        
            velocity = dir * dash_speed
            
            dash_charge -= 1
            dashing = true
            
            await get_tree().create_timer(dash_time).timeout
            dashing = false
            movement_lock = false


That's a long code sample. Can you reduce it to the minimum example that shows the behaviour you are trying to fix? stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (The process of reducing your code to the minimum example can often show you where your error is.) Also, you don't say how you are measuring the distance that is moved. Are you measuring it physically, or is it a value reported by your program?

Another tip: Your title doesn't describe the problem you are trying to solve. Maybe "diagonal movement shorter than horizontal/vertical movement in Godot" would be closer?

Currently you have the dir variable normalized which makes the movement of the character a constant distance away so it acts as a radius of which you can dash. At least I think I don't fully know how normalized vectors work but in 3D a normalized vector has a 3D spere of possible directions it can point, all with a force of 1. What you would need to do is to remove the normalized part and set a maximum distance of the x and y that you want the player to move. After that it should be ok. If it doesn't IDK  ¯\ (ツ) /¯
